# Error when calling Pkg_resources.resource_string

Tags: python, pkg-resources

I'm a little confused. I'm working on a Python project where I load a resource file, read it as tsv and transform it into a dictionary with pattern objects as key for later usage. To load the file, so far I've used the pkg_resources package from setuptools. It basically looks like this:

```
from csv import DictReader
from pkg_resources import resource_string

def make_dict():
    """Make global dictionary."""
    global event_dict
    dictlines = [l.decode('utf8') for l in resource_string(
            'pkgname.resources.tsv', 'event_dict.tsv').splitlines()]
    reader = DictReader(dictlines, dialect='excel-tab')
    for row in reader:
        event = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(row['word'])))
        classes = string_to_list(row['id'])
        event_dict[event] = classes
```

So far, it worked well. However, once I started calling the module from another module, following error appeared:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py in get_provider(moduleOrReq)
    430     try:
--> 431         module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]
    432     except KeyError:

KeyError: 'pkgname.resources.tsv'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-efa35954c76f> in <module>()
----> 1 make_event_dict()

<ipython-input-21-b318bc78e8fd> in make_event_dict()
      4     global event_dict
      5     dictlines = [l.decode('utf8') for l in resource_string(
----> 6             'pkgname.resources.tsv', 'event_classes_dict.tsv').splitlines()]
      7     reader = DictReader(dictlines, dialect='excel-tab')
      8     for row in reader:

C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py in resource_string(self, package_or_requirement, resource_name)
   1215     def resource_string(self, package_or_requirement, resource_name):
   1216         """Return specified resource as a string"""
-> 1217         return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_string(
   1218             self, resource_name
   1219         )

C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py in get_provider(moduleOrReq)
    431         module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]
    432     except KeyError:
--> 433         __import__(moduleOrReq)
    434         module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]
    435     loader = getattr(module, '__loader__', None)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkgname'
```

Now I'm guessing something's wrong with my project setup, so this is what it's structured like:

```
|Pkg\
|----setup.py
|----pkg\
|--------__init__.py
|--------events.py
|--------resources\
|------------__init__.py
|------------tsv\
|----------------__init__.py
|----------------event_dict.tsv
```

What could be wrong? Not exactly sure if the __init__.py in the subfolders are needed, btw.